# `documentclass` and required `packages` for compiling R help in tex

Tags: packages, document-classes, r

I got the help on `R` functions in `.tex` format using [help_console](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20969313/707145) function. I wonder what is the `documentclass` and required `packages` to compile this document correctly. Thanks in advance for your help. My MWE is:

---

**Code**

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

HeaderA{lm}{Fitting Linear Models}{lm}
aliasA{print.lm}{lm}{print.lm}
keyword{regression}{lm}
%
begin{Description}relax
code{lm} is used to fit linear models.
It can be used to carry out regression,
single stratum analysis of variance and
analysis of covariance (although code{LinkA{aov}{aov}} may provide a more
convenient interface for these).
end{Description}
%
begin{Usage}
begin{verbatim}
lm(formula, data, subset, weights, na.action,
   method = qr, model = TRUE, x = FALSE, y = FALSE, qr = TRUE,
   singular.ok = TRUE, contrasts = NULL, offset, ...)
end{verbatim}
end{Usage}
%


\end{document}
```

---

**Output**

---

[image]

Comment: I think this is done with the `sweave` tool chain...

Comment: Your code is wrong as all the `\commands` are lost (the obtained from  R really is `\HeaderA{lm}{Fitting Linear Models}{lm}
\aliasA{print.lm}{lm}{print.lm}` etc.

Comment: It looks like you lost the first column of the R output and are missing all the `\ `

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thanks for your comment. I've checked again and have not lost the first column of the R output.

Comment: well R has then, either way something has dropped the `\ ` (I notice the accepted answer doesn't give any indication of how to preserve the `\ ` other than not removing them.)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I don't know how preserve `\ ` because I cannot imagine how is missed.   Just with the help  of the link in the OP, in my R is always there. `:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The easy way**: Left to R do all the work.

```
help(lm,help_type="pdf")
```

You obtain in this way a PDF really complied with `pdflatex` with the R help.

**The hard way** (only useful if you want to modify the source before compiling):

**1) Locate `Rd.sty`**  (that you should have in your R installation).

> In a Linux system:
>
> ```
> $ locate Rd.sty
> /usr/lib/R/site-library/scatterplot3d/doc/Rd.sty
> /usr/share/R/share/texmf/tex/latex/Rd.sty
> ```

(If you have more than one, as in this case, your mileage may vary. The right here is the second.)

**2) Make a simple template document with de Rd package.** If LaTeX cannot find the path to `Rd.sty`, specify the absolute path, or make copy of this file to you working directory.

> ```
> \documentclass{article}
> \usepackage{/usr/share/R/share/texmf/tex/latex/Rd} 
> \begin{document}
> % paste your R code here
> \end{document}
> ```

**3) Paste the LaTeX chunk** obtained with the R `help_console` function (without lossing the `\` characters) in the template:

> ```
> \documentclass{article}
> \usepackage{/usr/share/R/share/texmf/tex/latex/Rd} 
> \begin{document}
> \HeaderA{lm}{Fitting Linear Models}{lm}
> \aliasA{print.lm}{lm}{print.lm}
> \keyword{regression}{lm}
> %
> \begin{Description}\relax
> \code{lm} is used to fit linear models.
> It can be used to carry out regression,
> .
> .
> .
> \end{document}
> ```

**4) Modify the contents**  (add, delete, change tex) of this file** as you want and/or  a local copy of `Rd.sty` to have your own style (redefining macros and environments, assuming that you know what are you doing). According to R documentation, *the appearance of the output can be also customized through a file ‘Rhelp.cfg’ somewhere in your LaTeX search path*, but I have not explored this option.

**5) Compile it** as usual with `pdflatex`.

Comment: (+1): Thanks @Fran for your answer. I need help document in `.tex` format to use in other documents. Can you explain the `1. Modify this file`?

Comment: @MYaseen208 You're welcome. About the step 3 (not 1, sorry): "modify as you want" . Of course, is optional, but I included this point because otherwise would only make sense the faster and easier method of obtain the PDF directly with the `help()` function. Right?

Comment: Thanks @Fran for your help. Do you know any easy way to export the obtained `.tex` document to `LyX`?

Comment: @MYaseen208 Have you tried from Lyx menu `File > Import > Latex` ? But probably many commands will remain as ERT boxes since  they are not common LaTeX commands.

Comment: Yes, I used `File > Import > Latex (plain)`. But this has some issues on my machine. It remove `ERT boxes` and `\` for some part of codes. Don't know why?

Comment: @MYaseen208. That  R help file is plenty of non standard LaTeX code that Lyx dont'kow how to manage. May be [creating a lyx layout](http://wiki.lyx.org/Layouts/CreatingLayouts) you can improve the result, but IMHO is too work for little (and not sure) benefit. I think that is better to stick with LaTeX with an editor with preview in real time as Gummi.